# ActiveAdmin username or password invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have successfully installed ActiveAdmin on my C9 Ruby on Rails environment but when I entered the default username and password, it came back as “Invalid Email or password.”

Here's what I did:

- Added `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` to my `Gemfile`
- Ran `bundle install`
- Ran `rails generate active_admin:install`
- Start the server with `rails server`
- Went to `localhost:3000/admin` and login screen appeared.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to go use rails console and create a known admin user.

`AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')`

Eventually you'd want to move this to your seeds file or something similar.

Comment: Thank you.  It is working now.  Surprisingly, there was no default email and password in the AdminUser table at all.  What a surprise!  The Active Admin documentation is rather misleading.

Comment: Here is another problem.  I was able to access Active Admin but when I tried updating my image, I got the following errors:    ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Admin::ProductsController#update

Extracted source (around line #21):
19
20
21
22
23
24
              
      def sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes)
        if attributes.respond_to?(:permitted?) && !attributes.permitted?
          raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
        else
          attributes
        end

Answer (score 3):

Go to `db/seeds.rb`

And you should have the following:

```
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
```

and in your console run:

```
rake db:seed
```

You can create loads of Admin users here for example:

```
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin1@example.com', password: 'password1', password_confirmation: 'password1')
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin2@example.com', password: 'password2', password_confirmation: 'password2')
```

And then create the by running `rake db:seed` in your console.

Lets say you have a `Post` model, now in your `admin/post.rb` you need something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
permit_params :title, :content, :author, :category, :image

show do |t|
  attributes_table do
    row :title
    row :content
    row :author
    row :category
    row :image do
      post.image? ? image_tag(post.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "nothing")
    end
  end
end

form :html => {:enctype => "multipart/form-data"} do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :title
    f.input :content
    f.input :author
    f.input :category
    f.input :image, hint: f.post.image? ? image_tag(post.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "upload here")
  end
  f.actions
end

end
```

Make sure you done all the paperclip generating etc

Comment: Thanks.  There is a problem uploading image on the Active Admin.  Is there anything else I have to install to fix my image uploading on Active Admin?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of active admin, once you run migrations

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb

```
create_user_code = "#{class_name}.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')"
```

So default user created is admin@example.com with password: password

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate active_admin:install` adds a line to `seed.db` to create the default username and password.

So just run `rails db:seed` and you're good to go.

I'm not sure why this isn't mentioned in the ActiveAdmin setup docs.